# Neo4J Graph Algorithms Cypher Projection should return only numbers?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hello I make a Graph Algorithm Neo4J request in Cypher of the following kind, which first finds the nodes and then the relations between them:

```
CALL algo.pageRank.stream('MATCH (u:User{uid:"0ee14110-426a-11e8-9d67-e79789c69fd7"}), 
(ctx:Context{name:"news180417"}), (u)<-[:BY]-(c:Concept)-[:AT]->(ctx) 
RETURN DISTINCT id(c) as id', 
'CALL apoc.index.relationships("TO","user:0ee14110-426a-11e8-9d67-e79789c69fd7") 
YIELD rel, start, end WITH DISTINCT rel, start, end MATCH (ctx:Context) 
WHERE rel.context = ctx.uid AND (ctx.name="news180417" ) 
RETURN DISTINCT id(start) AS source, id(end) AS target', 
{graph:'cypher', iterations:5});
```

Which works fine. However, when I try to return `c.uid` instead of its Neo4J `id()` the Graph Algorithms don't accept it.

Does it mean I can only operate using Neo4J ids in Graph Algorithms?

Comment: What is the error given by Graph Algorithms that indicates that it does not accept `c.uid`?

Comment: @RebeccaNelson that id Should be integer

Comment: It sounds like the library will not allow you to call a `MATCH` pattern that returns a non-int.

Comment: Exactly. So that was what the question was about.

Comment: Ah, sorry, it looks like I misinterpreted you. If the question is that "given this library says I can't return a String, can I return a string?" the answer is of course, "no, that is not possible". Are you looking for an alternate invocation or library that can accept label as a string value for PageRank?

Comment: @RebeccaNelson yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use [Cypher projection](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-graph-algorithms/#_cypher_projection) with the Graph Algorithms procedures, you pass 2 Cypher statements (and a config map).

The first Cypher statement must return an `id` variable whose value is the native ID of a node.

The second Cypher statement must return `source` and `target` variables whose values are also node IDs.

So, yes, your Cypher statements must always return neo4j native IDs.